# Can I install Ubuntu 14.04 on a laptop with builtin camera and mic?

Tags: 14.04, 12.10, upgrade, webcam, microphone

I bought a laptop with Ubuntu 12.10 installed, but I lost the installation CD. Now I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04. Can I do this without the CD? My laptop has a microphone and webcam. Will these work after an upgrade?

Comment: You should be able to use Ubuntu 14.04. It's highly unlikely that your camera and microphone will not work in Ubuntu 14.04. You can alternatively make a Live DVD/USB and test this.

Comment: thanks for your reply you allow me more questions? if I install the 14.04 version me solve the problems I have with version 12.10 and I functioned programs that did not work me again if I go back to the install? what happens is that I can not download programs due to a fault. so I would like to reinstall or upgrade change

Comment: Yes, it will. You're getting errors because Ubuntu 12.10 has reached end-of-life, and packages have been moved off to a different repo. See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) page on upgrading (if you decide to upgrade, you'll have to go through 13.10, which is also EOL).

Comment: but in the web i only found the last version to download
where I could find the version I need to upgrade? i read on the web I have to update to version vesion but not the place where i can locate it

Comment: @saiarcot895 I would not recommend to people to upgrade from short term releases to a long term release. These upgrades are not officially supported by Ubuntu, and often cause many problems. The user313111 will be best off is he does a fresh install.

Comment: @user313111 What is your native language? Also; Do not "Upgrade", but rather, do a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: my native language is spanish

Answer (score 1):

> I bought a laptop with Ubuntu 12.10 installed, but unfortunately I lost the installation CD.

That is no problem. Ubuntu is Open Source, ie, **FREE.** You can always download the latest version without any charge to you. However, if you wish to donate to the ubuntu project, that helps the cover the charges for development.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute

> I now want to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04, and I am wondering if I can do this without the installation CD?

Yes; you can upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 without a CD. For clear instructions, you can visit

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

To download the latest version of Ubuntu, visit:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

If English is not your first language, please comment below and we can find tutorials in your language.

> The laptop I own has a Microphone and Web Camera; Will these both work if perform an upgrade?

Yes.

Comment: thanks for your answer. True that the it is not my language and it is a little difficult to write for me but i understand the english , sorry for my wrong write

Comment: my natal language is spanish

Comment: i recommended  then get settled ubuntu 13 or 14? (que me recomendaria me instalo ubuntu 13 o 14? y me lo instalo o me lo actualizo?)

Comment: @user313111 http://www.ubuntu-es.org & http://askubuntu.com/questions/507888/ubuntu-support-communities-for-spanish-espanol-speakers << Answers pending. :)

Comment: @user313111 Only use Ubuntu 14.04. It will be supported for 3 years.  **DO NOT USE UBUNTU 13.04 or 13.10** Ubuntu 13.04/Ubuntu 13.10 are no longer supported.

Comment: @user313111 If you feel the question has been answered, it is appreciated if you press the checkmark to accept this as an answer. This helps keep the stack exchange clean.